# Is there a good script similar to Iconfinder.com?

Tags: search-engine

Basically I'm looking for a search engine that searches through a given database.  The content will be text being searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use a service such as [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). The easiest way to get started using it is to find a 'cloud' based version, such as [Websolr](http://www.websolr.com/). However, the solution will depend on what language you wish to use when programming your site.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions depend somewhat on language:
1. For java/c#, you have lucene/solr
2. for python you have haystack
You could do text search in the DB directly via LIKE/ILIKE, but the performance depends on DB.

Answer (score 0):

Iconfinder was coded specifically for icon search and at the time (launched in 2007) there were no scripts that worked well for this.

Building a search engine like Iconfinder is not rocket science. I think the hardest part is getting the SQL tuned and figure out how to rank the content. At the moment I collect data about impressions and downloads and calculate a value from that. The icons' rank is based on this value (download/impression) and how well keywords match the tags for the given icon.

Comment: Oh wow, i'm honored to have iconfinder site owner to post a reply.  Your site is an amazing resource.  In regards to my question, i'd be in your debt if you can explain more in depth in terms of how you search for results, ie. do you simply have a MySQL table in which you query each id and return anything that is related to the search term (in terms of ranking i plan to have a rating system implemented).  By the way, i am in no means looking to start a similar site, i just really like iconfinder's simple interface, i'm looking to start something along a student resource db.  Thanks again.